# DateRangePicker Calendar rendering wrong

Tags: jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I'm using [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) to select a range of dates.  While everything works fine, the calendar ui which renders to choose dates does not display the dates in the right order.

[Here is an image for the calendar for the month of July rendered by daterangepicker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC2l6.png)

1st of July starts from Saturday but in the calendar it's wrong and the rest of the dates are shifted down weirdly.

Below is my daterangepicker settings.

**Edit** added js/css based on the comments

```js
$(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange input').html(start + ' - ' + end);
  }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
      "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    },
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" id="reportrange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
```

below is the order of files as included in my project.

```
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/1.13.1-jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level plugins -->
<script src="~/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page level custom scripts -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<script src="~/js/Common.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

HTML element to which dateRangePicker is attached

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 mt-2">
                <div class="input-group  ml-4 mb-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control col-md-3" id="reportrange" placeholder="Updated On" />
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Make sure CSS is loaded properly.

Comment: I have added all the files in the order as specified in the [link] (https://www.daterangepicker.com/)

Comment: Can you reproduce same error in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, click `[<>]` and add the links/scripts into the snippet editor to make a working snippet that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: `$('#reportrange input').html(start + ' - ' + end);` doesn't look right as if it's an `input` then it will need to be `.val(start + ...`

Comment: Your code seems to work fine  https://jsfiddle.net/3o8keyfb/  given the details provided.

Comment: @KiranShahi I tried it on jsFiddle and I'm not able to replicate it. It works completely fine there.

Comment: I've also converted your code here on SO to a snippet, where it also works fine.  If we can't reproduce the issue, then we can only guess at the problem - eg wrong css / *additional/custom css* breaking the layout / etc

Comment: @freedomn-m I think the same too, maybe the jquery is breaking the code? I haven't added any custom styling to the input element.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be css against the input - just some css in general.  Try without any of your custom css and see if it works, then add parts piece by piece until it breaks.

Comment: I went through my whole css and it was an existing style that was interfering with daterangepicker. I had a class by name "off" and had some styles applied to it and apparently daterangepicker also uses a class name "off". I've made the necessary changes and it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS file not loading here. This is the issue with the CSS file placing after JS script tags. Try to move the below CSS file link tag to head section and place on top of all script tags. Hope this will work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your snippet. It works fine. Please check your distorted section css using inspect element. I think some other css overlapped the css of date range.
If you see the overlapping occurs then download the date range css and include the css file from your own directory and use !important in the ignored CSS. Hope this idea helps you.